# extjs + openlayers adding easy functionality

Tags: javascript, extjs, html-lists, gis, openlayers-3

I'm learning extjs6 + openlayers3.
Most tutorials are from previous versions so I can not find solution for some things. Here is my working code.

```
Ext.application({    
    name   : 'MyApp',
    launch :  function() {
        var map = new ol.Map({                  
            layers: [    
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ], 
            target: 'map',  
            view: new ol.View({
                center: [0, 0],
                zoom: 2                         
            })
        });
    }       
});
```

The question is: How can I add some functionality to this?
For example something like this:

```
map.addControl(new ol.Control.PanZoomBar());
```

Comment: I ones created something like this, but with arcgis, and I created a `Ext.Container` with a config property 'map'. In the init of that component I created the map and put that on 'map'. Now I can, from a controller for example, do something like `container.getMap().addControl` or bind events etc.

Comment: Have you seen [GeoExt 3](http://geoext.github.io/geoext3/)?